# Is there a general formula for the del operator $\nabla$ in different coordinate systems?

Tags: vector-analysis

The $\nabla$-operator is simple in cartesian coordinates, $[\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z]$, but in spherical coordinates, it becomes $[\partial_r, \frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta, \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\partial_\varphi]$ and in cylindrical coordinates $[\partial_\rho, \frac{1}{\rho}\partial_\varphi, \partial_z]$; is there a general formula for converting into a different coordinate system, perhaps in terms of a Jacobian?

(Sub-question: Is there any reason why similar operators like $\hat{\nabla} = [\partial_r, \partial_\theta, \partial_\varphi]$ aren't in use?)

Comment: To the subquestion: we know that $\nabla$ transforms as a vector under rotations. How does $\hat{\nabla}$ transform?.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: This is because vector calculus notation is full of old fashioned notions.
If you want to understand what is going on with the $\nabla$ operator in vector calculus, you should really use the modern language of differential forms. You can see that all the operators $\text{div}$, $\text{curl}$, $\text{grad}$, $\text{lapl}$ are just different combinations of something called the exterior derivative $\text{d}$ and the Hodge dual $\star$, and all integral theorems (Gauss, Stokes, fundamental theorem of calculus) are just different expressions of a single one (Kelvin-Stokes).

Answer (score 1):

There is a large body of literature on this subject. I found a section in an old calculus book on Orthogonal Curvilinear Coordinates in the chapter on Vector Analysis. It's too complex to present here. (The book is *Advanced Calculus for Applications* by Hildebrand.) However, you can get started here: [Curvilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates).